# Caption against margins, without hanging

Tags: captions, subfloats

I want to keep the figure caption in the second line to start from the left margin.
I am using `subcaption` package. Please give me a solution.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)? It will tell us what package you use and how to help you.

Comment: If this is for a publication, they may require hanging indentation for captions.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the `format` of your captions set to `hang`. Here's what that looks like with `hang`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx}

\captionsetup{
  labelfont=bf,
  format=hang% <------------- Remove
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \subcaptionbox{Original state}
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
  \hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Longitudinal load}
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-b}}%
  \hfill
  \subcaptionbox{Transverse load}
    {\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-c}}%

  \caption{Illustration of piezoelectric effect in a quartz crystal: (a)~Regular
    hexagonal crystal structure with electrodes. (b)~and (c)~Lattice
    distortion of the crystal generating field upon an
    applied mechanical force.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And without `hang`:

[image]